# How does jailbreakme work?

Tags: exploit

jailbreakme.com is a website that jailbreaks your iPhone on the website. It downloads the installer, and then it installs it. How does a website download something and install it? How is that slider made on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some info about how it works here: [JailbreakMe 2.0 Uses PDF Exploit](http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002002.html)

Answer (score 1):

It works because of a security vulnerability in iOS that allows pdfs to execute arbitrary code. The website exploits this to install jailbreak software.

As for the slider, it uses javascript and WebKit transform. If you want more detailed info, just look at the source code for the site.